# Zoom out window in wpf

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

How do I simply Zoom out a window WPF? I do not want any slider control, all I want is for the window to be zoomed out slowly when the program is executed. I would appreciate a piece of code for that in XAML.

I am using VS 2010 with .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Window
   x:Name="window"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   AllowsTransparency="True"
   SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
   WindowStyle="None">
   <Canvas x:Name="grid">
      <Canvas.RenderTransform>
         <ScaleTransform x:Name="zoom" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
      </Canvas.RenderTransform>
      <Canvas.Triggers>
         <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
               <BeginStoryboard>
                  <Storyboard>
                     <DoubleAnimation
                        Duration="00:00:03"
                        From="400"
                        Storyboard.TargetName="grid"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                        To="200"/>
                     <DoubleAnimation
                        Duration="00:00:03"
                        From="400"
                        Storyboard.TargetName="grid"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                        To="200"/>
                     <DoubleAnimation
                        Duration="00:00:03"
                        From="1"
                        Storyboard.TargetName="zoom"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"
                        To="0.5"/>
                     <DoubleAnimation
                        Duration="00:00:03"
                        From="1"
                        Storyboard.TargetName="zoom"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY"
                        To="0.5"/>
                  </Storyboard>
               </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
         </EventTrigger>
      </Canvas.Triggers>
      <StackPanel Width="200" Height="200">
         <Button>Hello world!</Button>
         <ListBox>
            <ListBoxItem>One</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Two</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Three</ListBoxItem>
         </ListBox>
      </StackPanel>
   </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but, what you are doing is zooming in a stack panel. I do not want any controls in the window to zoom. I want the whole window to zoom out.

Comment: You mean, zoom out a whole window including its header and border? If so, well, you can try to emulate this kind of zooming by disabling window borders (WindowStyle = None) and mocking its style using WPF controls. You have to implement all its controls (such as minimize button, close button, dragging) and using a ScaleTransform plus manual window size changing, you can solve your problem.

Comment: yes, I want the whole window zoomed out. I did disable the borders and stuff. There is no need to implement its controls like close and minimize. All I want is a border less and title less window zoom out. Can you help.